# Given an integer $2A$ and a function $p$, how many sets there are such that #$S=k$ and $p^k(m)=m$ for $m$ in $S$

Tags: number-theory, logic

Given an integer $2A$ and a piecewise function $p$:

$p(n) =
\begin{cases}
2n,  & \text{if $1 \le n \le A$} \\
2(n-A)-1, & \text{if $A \lt n \le 2A$}
\end{cases}$

Determine what are the values of $k$ that makes possible the existence of sets $S$ such that #$S=k$ and $p^k(m)=m$ for all $m$ in $S$, and for each value of $k$, determine how many and what are the sets $S$.

Comment: do you mean $1\leq  n\leq A$?

Comment: Right, I edited it.